# window.setTimeout Not Firing

Tags: javascript

I'm sure I'll hate myself when I find out what the issue is, but I can't for the life of me figure out why this won't work.  I'm using setTimeout elsewhere in the site just like this and it is working fine.

```
<input type='button' value='Submit Form' onclick='ValidateForm()'/>
var submitFinalTimeout;
function ValidateForm() {
        //Performing a number of validations which may return false;

        //I know that the following if condition evaluates as true.  But just for giggles I tried moving it outside of the if and it still never fires.
        if (types.indexOf("K2") != -1) {
            submitFinalTimeout = window.setTimeout(function () { alert("Timeout set"); }, 2000);
            validateK2();
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

When I say validate, I mean I am alerting the use if an issue is found and returning false to prevent the validation from continuing.  The return values of true or false do not affect whether or not page posts.

I've tried also removing everything else inside of the curly braces to ensure no other code was conflicting with it.  I have literally tried removing ALL other code withing the ValidateForm function except for the setTimeout and it still never fires.

I saw a similar post where the issue was some other javascript error on the page preventing it from working.  But neither my developer console in Chrome nor firebug show any errors or any kind on the page.  Just a few warnings about interpreting an image.

Comment: How is `ValidateForm` called?

Comment: Have you made a log to check that `ValidateForm()` is *actually* being called?

Comment: @jmease: Show it, along with what `types` is.

Comment: Yes.  I know that both the ValidateForm function and the if statement work as described because the validateK2 function executes.

Comment: Does the form get submitted after `ValidateForm` is ran?  Does the page get redirected before the timeout gets a chance to fire?

Comment: No.  As I said, I have literally tried removing ALL other code and it still never fires.

Comment: Show the button code, do not say it executes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `ValidateForm` is called when a form is being submitted. The reason you're not seeing the function called by `setTimeout` is that the page is torn down completely by a form submission, and then replaced by the result.

Comment: I agree, was hoping to see the button code before posting it. :)

Comment: The ValidateForm function fires as the result of a button click.  It is an html input and does not post the page.  It is not in any way tied to the form "submitting"

Comment: @jmease: Okay. (I frankly don't believe that, since if it were true the function **would** get called two seconds later, but that's fine.) If you give us more context, maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

i want to echo the other commenters: you're *sure* that the function is being called and that the conditional is being evaluated to true?

i set up [a JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/domKosmix/g8uuD/). everything seems fine, assuming that ValidateForm() is actually called and (types.indexOf("K2") != -1) is true:

```
        if (true || types.indexOf("K2") != -1) {
            submitFinalTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() { alert("Timeout set"); }, 2000);
        }
....

        //call the function
        ValidateForm();
```